# Iteration over collection early termination

Tags: clojure

I have a reduce with an anonymous function with a persistent array map as parameter (and a map to accumulate a result). So during reducing, the lambda function will iterate on **all** key/val pairs. Yet I need to stop the whole reduction process upon a condition. The problem is that 'reduced' terminate only for the **current** key and does not prevent to continue to the following and the result to be accumulated as if I haven't matched the condition!

```
(defn my-func [my-map src]
  (reduce (fn [acc [k v]] ; on cond I want to stop look on [k v] pairs and exit reuction and even my-func !!! 
    (assoc acc (key value))) (empty src) my-map))
```

What I expect is a way to terminate early with, say an empty value as result.

Comment: It is considered helpful to publish the code you have trouble with.

Comment: It sounds like you should look at `reductions`.

Comment: I've tried to include your code in the question, but it isn't actually using reduced so it's hard to tell where things are going awry.

Comment: "The problem is that 'reduced' terminate only for the current key" - no, it's not. `(reduce (fn [acc x] (println x) (if (>= x 2) (reduced ::early) (+ acc x))) 0 [1 2 3 4])` prints "1", "2", and then returns `::early`. Maybe you're just doing it wrong: `reduced` is not a side effect (unlike `throw`), it should be returned from the reduce function, rather than just called. Also remember that maps are commonly unordered, so you can't rely on order of keys in search of the specific key, maybe that is the problem? Anyway it would be nice, if you could show the code with`reduced` that doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

reduced "works":

```
(reduce #(if (< %2 100) %2 (reduced :one-hundred)) (range 1 100))
99
(reduce #(if (< %2 100) %2 (reduced :one-hundred)) (range 1 101))
:one-hundred
```

However the order of iteration of a map or a set may not be what you expect:

```
(reduce #(if (< %2 1000) (inc %1) (reduced %1)) 0 (apply hash-set (range 1000)))
1000
(reduce #(if (< %2 999) (inc %1) (reduced %1)) 0 (apply hash-set (range 1000)))
510
(reduce #(if (< %2 998) (inc %1) (reduced %1)) 0 (apply hash-set (range 1000)))
157
```

Trying to match the form that you have, with some simplifications. This version will copy the input map, unless key :a is present when it will reduce to an empty map.

```
(defn my-func [m]
  (reduce (fn [acc [k v]]
            (if (= k :a) (reduced {}) ;; if cond return empty
                (assoc acc k v))) {} m))
(my-func {:b 4 :c 7})
;; =>
{:b 4, :c 7}

(my-func {:a 2 :d 6})
;; =>
{}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes reduced works in such a case, but mine is a little bit more complicated: here is what my code looks like :                                                                     (defn my-func [my-map src]
      (reduce (fn [acc [k v]]

        ; on cond I want to stop look on [k v] pairs and exit reuction and even my-func !!!

        (assoc acc (key value)))
(empty src)
my-map))

Comment: @StéphaneMichaut Please add this code to your question.  It's not prominent enough here and helps to clarify alot about your problem.

Comment: Yes you are right reduced works fine for my case. Thanks to your example I understood my error: I had a misplaced paranthese !

Comment: This is why it’s super important to include the actual code you are having trouble with in the question:-) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question: If your map has a key and/or value that fulfills a condition, you want to not process the map, but simply return some marker that you exited early.  You could use a loop for that:

```clj
(defn my-func [my-map]
  (loop [m my-map]
    (if-let [[k v] (first m)]
      (if (= v 4) ;; your condition for exit-early
        :four     ;; return your exit-early marker
        (recur (rest m)))
      my-map))) ;; you looped throught the whole map without exit-early
(my-func {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4 :e 5})
```

You could even pass in the exit-early-predicate and a marker as arguments:

```clj
(defn my-func [my-map kv-exit-pred marker]
  (loop [m my-map]
    (if-let [[k v] (first m)]
      (if (kv-exit-pred k v) 
        marker     
        (recur (rest m)))
      my-map))) 
(my-func {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4 :e 5} #(= %2 3) :three)
```

In both cases, if you don't exit early, then simply return the original map (as that is what your reduce-function does in practice).